# Starting process in new Terminal window on Mac

Tags: c, macos, terminal, console

On Windows I can do `CreateProcess(..., CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, ...)` and my child process (which is console app, not GUI) will be launched in a new window. What is the easiest way to emulate this on Mac OS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`open -a Terminal.app $(which program)`** gets a new terminal running the specified program (assuming you're using bash).

You can use **`execve()`** (possible after a **`fork()`**) to acheive the same thing in compiled code without knowing any Apple APIs (I imagine there is a proper way to do this...).

Read **`man open`**.

Edit: you don't need to specify the path to Terminal.app (the finder can figure that out).

---

If you have X running, it is even easier: just spawn a new xterm with **`xterm -e program &`**.

Read **`man xterm`** (which will take longer...).

---

I'll second Chris about the correct use (or lack thereof) of CLI for ordinary mac programs. In my buisness this is expected but the typical user will be {confused|angry|unhappy}.

Answer (score 6):

The Terminal (Terminal.app, what you're referring to as "the console") is just another user-level application on Mac OS X, not a capability of the operating system.  There is no direct way in the various APIs available on Mac OS X to just start an executable within a new Terminal window.

However, I believe you can open an executable with Terminal as if it was a document — whether in code or as a user — and it will run in a new session.  However, this is **not** a normal Mac OS X user experience and **should not** generally be used in Mac software you're going to deliver to end users.

Mac OS X applications are applications.  It's fine to provide tools that advanced users can interact with via Terminal, but Terminal is in no way, shape or form a substitute for a real application when delivering software to end users.

I'll add to this that if you're using Cocoa, you can use the [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to start and interact with another process very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Marc Liyanage does this neatly with "term", osascript tell application "Terminal":
http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Mac+OS+X/2005/02/28/Terminal_tricks_8220_term_8221_and_8220_clone_8221.html

(On "typical users": there are different universes, each finding the others strange.
Coming from Unix, I'm used to a process or "| pipe args" anywhere a file can be used;
this helps software componentry immensely.
But open -a does files only -- different universe).